# access the values present in a table cells using jquery in IE7

Tags: jquery

I am trying to access the values of the cells of a table using jquery in IE7.

```
 <div class="tablecontainer" id="TOPSalesProfileDetail">
<table class="panelTable">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="tableDOM_consumptionProfile">
                <div class="tableContainer" id="tableContainer_consumptionProfile">
                    <table class="table" id="consumptionProfile" rules="all" jQuery1332936697920="28">
                        <tbody id="body_consumptionProfile">
                            <tr class="" id="consumptionProfile_0" lineNumber="0">
                                <td class="evenCell" id="consumptionProfile_0_consumptionProfileCoeffientEnteredValue">
                                    <input class="field" id="consumptionProfile_0_consumptionProfileCoeffientEnteredValue_Field" style="width: auto;" jQuery1332936697920="21" value="5"/>
                <div class="tableButtons" id="tableButtonsconsumptionProfile"/>
```

I tried $("#consumptionProfile_0_consumptionProfileCoeffientEnteredValue_Field").val() to get the value present in the input field with id "consumptionProfile_0_consumptionProfileCoeffientEnteredValue_Field",
but it is not working.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please post the related js code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UA99m/

Probably the markup have some dynamic id which is different every time you load the page, or the jquery statement is called too early (is it inside the ready callback?).

Comment: Too early?I am creating the table using javascript inside a div , and i am using the above jquery statement before attaching the div containing the table  to the page.Is that a problem ?